# Which one is safer? sudo dnf update OR su - ; dnf update

Tags: security, sudo, su, setuid

Is it safer to do:

1. `$ sudo dnf update` [enter user password]

**or**

2. ```
   $ su - [enter root password]
   # dnf update
   ```

I always assumed they are the exact same thing, because sudo utilizes setuid-root, so the process that is run as sudo's first arg is run with the sudo's effective ID, which is root.

**I guess my question is:** Does sudo eventually drops its effective ID to the normal user's?  Then in that case, number 1 above would be a safer bet, because if the program sudo is running with is compromised by an attacker, then there is a chance that the attacker is not running as root, because the privilege has already been dropped?

Comment: IMHO the problem is not a very hypothetical attacker. The problem is you forgetting in the 2nd case that the command prompt is running as root and damaging system files.

Comment: If a program is compromised while executed with sudo, is that the same thing as being the superuser, and running a the same program and getting it compromised? Sorry if that sounds redundant, i don't know if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This first command will (probably) require your correct password, run `dnf update` as root, and then exit:

> ```
> $ sudo dnf update [enter user password]
> ```

This second command will require root's password and then start a root shell. In that shell you run `dnf update`:

> ```
> $ su - [enter root password]
> # dnf update
> ```

You're not really comparing like for like. You could compare these two commands, both of which start a root shell in which you run (at least) the command `dnf update`

```
sudo -s
dnf update

su -
dnf update
```

Or you could compare these two commands, both of which start a root-privileged instance of `dnf update` and then exit back to caller's shell

```
sudo dnf update

su root -c 'dnf update'
```

What I think you're actually asking is whether it's better to invoke a single command with root privileges, or start a root-privileged shell in which to run one or more commands.

- If the `dnf` functionality or its downloads are compromised in some way then it doesn't matter how it's run, the issue is that it's run at all
- If you're talking about compromising your system then it comes down to the security of the user's password (`sudo`) vs root's password (`su`)
- If you're considering whether you can trust the user , then it doesn't really matter whether you get a root shell in which you run multiple commands or a root shell to run one command at a time; the issues is that commands can be run as root

Personally I mix and match my usage depending on need. I rarely use `su` but I do use `sudo {command....}` for quick one-offs or `sudo -s` for a short session where I need to run multiple commands (for example Debian package management tools, `apt-get update` followed by `apt-get upgrade`).

Comment: Thank you @roaima I was definitely trying to see if in a scenario like if I had a pc that has a root account and a regular user account. The root password is strong and the regular user account my roommate/friends all know. I disabled my wheel group in sudoer file so there are no sudo/admin/wheel group can do system commands as root. Any real work I do that needs root like ‘dnf update’ I can just switch user to root and then perform necessary tasks and exit root shell. This way if someone with my password gets a hold of my system they cannot do any system level harm at least

Comment: Wasn’t sure if for any reason that’s not safer to do than ‘sudo’ guess I was just paranoid about it.

Comment: @Rennitbaby by default, `sudo` uses the user's password to control switching to a root account but `su` requires the root password. The setting for `sudo` can be easily changed to require the root password. Incidentally, you might want to consider giving your friends their own accounts rather than yours. These are multi-user systems, after all.

Comment: Thank you for that tip, looked up the root password flag, that is the best solution

Answer (score 1):

Yes `sudo` drops privileges when the child process ends. In this case `dnf`. Where as `su` drops privileges when the child process ends. In this case an interactive shell. Therefore the `sudo` example drops privilege sooner.

`sudo` also has other advantages not covered here. (e.g. the `sudoers` file, can be used to give more control on what each user can and can not do).